# Quartz.NET Updating a Calendar after creating Job

Tags: quartz.net

I've searched online, but cant find the answer. I'd like to know if I create a Job, JobDetail, and Trigger with a Holiday Calendar (for excluding dates), how can I maintain that calendar? I noticed a calendar table created by Quartz.net, but that merely contains the calendar name.

Essentially I'd be adding a Job with a holiday calendar attached to its trigger, however the calendar may change in future which will affect the next run time. How should I approach this?

Comment: I also have this problem. I m using Quartz in Spring boot and i want to update that calendar after creating the job, job detail, trigger with a holiday calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `IScheduler.AddCalendar`? There are 'replace' and 'updateTrigger' flags on this method. Here's a code sample (untested):

```cs
        IScheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
        var holidayCalendar = new HolidayCalendar();
        holidayCalendar.AddExcludedDate(new DateTime(2013,1,1));
        scheduler.AddCalendar("existingCalendar", holidayCalendar, true, true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that really helps as if the name of the calendar needs to change you just can't do it without deleting and replacing it...